# Error when function start_chrome() from helium called

Tags: python, web-scraping, visual-studio-code, kali-linux, helium

when I run this code:

```
from helium import *

start_chrome()
```

I am getting this error : `NameError: name 'start_chrome' is not defined`
Help with this. Funny thing is yesterday it was working.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code in VS Code and the results showed that it can run:

[image]

Please check whether the current python environment contains the module "helium" in the VS Code terminal.

[image]

Also, please try to reload VS Code to make it recognize the module.

My environment:

VS Code: 1.53.2 (user setup); Python:3.8; python extension: 2021.2.582707922; Jupyter extension: 2021.2.576440691

```
"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
```

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041